# Combining Systems Engineering and Cosmology/Astrophysics

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology

in a nutshell, my undergrad was in Astrophysics, my master's is in Systems Engineering (SE), and I am currently completing my Ph.D. in SE focusing on deep learning applications towards engineering design systems.

My question is:

*Is there a way to combine SE and astrophysics?*

Before anyone asks, why didn't I continue in astro? because I am in the military, and there is no distance-learning astrophysics programs at the PhD level.

Comment: No shortage of applications of deep learning in astronomy.

Comment: Big data + pattern matching = machine learning. This has astronomy written all over it.

Comment: A very recent example is the [sharpening of the 2017 black hole image using machine learning techniques](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/acc32d).

Comment: So, it is possible for an engineer to be a part of cutting edge cosmology research?

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer is: yes.

Aside from the fact that machine learning is used in theoretical studies, like in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-abstract/522/1/1270/7116485) or in [this one](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ac5019), your combined expertise would be invaluable in designing and operating astrophysical instrumentation.

NASA should be on top of your list. Good luck with your job search. I am sure you will find something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will definitely look into it